# java do extended classes have two types

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

In java I have the following:

```
ClassA obj = new ClassB();
```

where `ClassB extends ClassA`.
Is obj of type `ClassA` or `ClassB` or both?

if we have instead:

```
ClassB obj = new ClassB();
```

it seems clear that `obj` is of type `ClassB` but all `ClassB` are `ClassA` too, aren't they? So is the type both `ClassA` and `ClassB`?

if we add the following:

```
ClassA [] objects = new ClassA[3];
ClassA obj = new ClassB();
objects[0] = obj;
```

it seems that `obj` is of type `ClassA`. So we can add it to objects even though obj is a `new ClassB();`

Here's my confusion, let say we have an overwritten method in `ClassB` from `ClassA`, I can call the method and I get the expected output from the `ClassB` overwritten method.  But, if I have just a `ClassB` method not also contained in `ClassA` I can't call it and I don't seem to be able to upcast it to `ClassB`.  oh wait, `obj` is of type `ClassA` so we can't cast it to a `ClassB` because all `ClassA`'s aren't `ClassB`'s.

So obj is of type `ClassA` but we set it to `new ClassB()`. so what the heck is it? Is it `ClassA` or `ClassB`, I'm so confused. Why can we access the overwritten methods in `ClassB` but not the non overwritten methods?  Is that just the way polymorphism works?

Comment: I don't mind the downvote but a little explanation as to why would be really helpful

Comment: Do you know the difference between the static and the dynamic type of an object?

Comment: Take a look at [static vs. dynamic binding](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-dynamic-binding).

Comment: @Mushroomator that is only part of the puzzle (dynamic dispatch/binding). There are more nuances. E.g. when an overloaded method is called, the exact implementation called is determined by the static types of the actual parameters.

Comment: clear as mud.  Does anyone one have a clearer explanation suitable for a highschool classroom

Comment: The downvotes come from the fact that this a fundamental aspect of Java that is extremely well documented all over the Internet.  One of the SO tenets is that we'd rather not re-document stuff that can already be found elsewhere, and you're expected to have done the research before asking.

Comment: wow, I've looked all over the internet and all of the explanations are as I said, clear as mud

Comment: [This pdf from `www.cs.cornell.edu`](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/JavaAndDS/files/staticType.pdf) explains static and dynamic types quite well and with a concrete examples. For completeness: the static type determines what we "see" when we write code: When the variable has the static type `Animal`, we only see methods defined in `Animal`. The dynamic type, however, determines (through dynamic dispatch) which implementation of a method is called (aside from overloading, which falls back to the static types and is a separate topic).

Comment: The compile-time type is `ClassA`. You can only reference methods that are know to the compile-time type. But the actual invocation is resolved against the runtime type, namely `ClassB`. So if a method declared in `ClassA` is overridden in `ClassB`, it's the latter version that gets invoked. It's fundamental to polymorphism that you can have a shared "contract" for multiple types with varying implementations depending on subtype of a particular instance. This is supposed to reflect real-world objects in the sense that you can describe e.g. how to drive a car without knowing the specific model.

Comment: @user16320675 "*it sure can be done in Java*" - Can it be done? yes. Should it be done? Probably not. At least not without at least a preceeding type check. Even then: the uses should be few and far between. See the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @user16320675, thanks I didn't realize I need to add the extra set of ()

Comment: @JimGarrison The information may be _"all over the Internet"_ but that does not, and never should, preclude users from asking here. I'd also note that so far nobody has proposed a duplicate for the OP's question, which suggests it may not have been asked before on SO. Given that the question is about _"a fundamental aspect of Java"_, if nobody has asked it here before it is actually a good and very useful question.

Comment: “All over the Internet” and doesn’t provide a single reference. Nice job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is identical to this situation:

You see Max, who is a poodle. You ask: So, what's the deal? Is Max a Poodle, a Dog, or an Animal? Or all three at the same time?

The answer is more or less 'that question belies a misunderstanding of how we classify living things'. If you must choose from your limited set of options, "It is all 3" is more correct than any other. But that implies you could create a Poodle that is also an Animal but *not* a Dog, and that is the wrong conclusion: *Anything that is a poodle is **necessarily** also a Dog*.

It also depends on context. If I ask about the 'type' of creature that Max is, and the situation calls for just one answer, you always get 'Poodle'. Because that's the most useful answer - knowing that max is a Poodle is enough to determine that max is therefore necessarily also a dog and also an animal because *by definition, **all** poodles are. You can't have a non-dog creature that is nevertheless a poodle*.

Hence:

- `Animal a = new Poodle();` is perfectly legal. Al poodles are animals, so, if you have a job that requires any animal, a poodle will work. So would a chihuahua.
- Java does everything by reference. `Animal a;` is like declaring the existence of a little post-it note named `a` which is to contain the **adress** of where some animal lives. The address can even be left blank (`null`). You are guaranteed that, if an actual address is on this post-it note, that it will **definitely** lead to some sort of animal (it would not lead to, say, an oak tree, the language and runtime **guarantee** this). In this case, it would, in fact, lead to a poodle. Which works fine: all poodles are animals, after all. The fact that your address postit says 'I might lead to any animal' doesn't magically turn max into a donkey or even into a 'generic animal' - max remains a poodle:

```
Poodle max = new Poodle();
Animal a = max;
System.out.println(a.getClass()); // prints 'Poodle'.
```

Remember, the dot operator is 'follow the address on the post-it and ask the thing you find there a question'. `.getClass()` doesn't 'ask the question' to `a`, it asks the question to the thing a is pointing at. Currently, a is pointing at max. And if you ask Max what he is (and if dogs could speak, I guess), max would say 'I am a poodle'. Max won't say "I am an animal"; max has no awareness of the postit note, and really couldn't: There could be 85 postits all with the address of max. There could be none left (local variables cease existing once a method ends, for example, as if the postit note poofs into oblivion). When asking questions to objects they don't get the 'context' (what route you used to *find* that object), and thus you know their answer cannot possibly be dependent on it.

- `Poodle b = a;` **is not** legal. This means: "Take the address on post-it note a and copy it over to post-it note b, which is restricted such that, if it points to anything, it points to a poodle. **Even if** a is currently pointing at a poodle, at compile time the compiler doesn't know that, so it won't let you do this. Not without a cast: `Poodle b = (Poodle) a;` is fine, because that is interjecting: "Check if a is in fact pointing at a poodle. If it is indeed, then all is well. But if not, stop everything you are doing and exit this procedure abnormally with a 'ClassCastException'.
- Objects always have many, many types. For example, `new ArrayList<String>` is **all** of these things: `Serializable`, `RandomAccess`, `Iterable<String>`, `ArrayList<String>`, `AbstractList<String>`, `List<String>`, `AbstractCollection<String>`, `Collection<String>`, `Object`, and perhaps a few more I missed. It's not just the type hierarchy (ArrayList extends AbstractList extends AbstractCollection extends Object), it's also all the interfaces you pick up along the way - and all of *their* superinterfaces too. This matches real life. max is a poodle, a dog, an animal, a meat eater, a legged thing, a source of pee, a 2-eared thing, male, and so many other things. All at the same time.